# Datepicker se muestra en color blanco

Tags: css, datepicker, bootstrap-3

Buen dia, tengo un problema al querer poner un datepicker en mi codigo, no me muestra los dias de la semana, nombre del mes y algunos botones.. bueno si los muestra pero estan en color blanco alguien sabe como puedo modificar esto?

Estoy usando

- Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.7.1 (https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)
- Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)

[image: Calendar]

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema de CSS, puede ser que estás utilizando la clase datepicker-switch en otro lado (en bootstrap puede haber conflicto)

Te recomiendo que desde tu css agregues:

```
.datepicker .datepicker-switch, .datepicker .next, .datepicker .prev, .datepicker tfoot tr th {
 color: #000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Ya lo solucione, esta linea que me pasaste no pinta el nombre de los dias solo el nombre de mes, con esta linea quedo.. Gracias!